# Combine date/time from different columns in HAVING clause

Tags: sql, having

I'm trying to compare a combination of max date and max time from two different columns, yet the problem is that when I do so it takes the max date and max time even when they aren't in the same row. Here is the HAVING statement:

```
having mask(max(wijzKode.tsacdt), 'jjjjmmdd') ||
mask(max(wijzKode.tsacty), 'hhmm') <=
mask(today, 'jjjjmmdd') ||
mask(now, 'hhmm')
```

Comment: If the max date and max time are not in the same row, select them separately using subqueries and then do what you need to do.

Comment: @DanBracuk how do you mean? today and now are correct(obviously) but tsacdt and tsacty give date and time from different rows. I can't place a select in my having clause if I'm correct.